# Embedding one part of a page on to another site

Tags: javascript, html, embed

http://ucdigtimes.limewebs.com/digTimeClocks.php

At that page, there are three timers. Id love to be able to figure out how to embed just that part onto another page. I was able to embed the whole page, which is not what I want.

We use the timers for a game, and the game will allow me to use html. Not really sure if it will let me embed using javascript, but if that is the only way, I could give it a go.

Comment: You want those same clocks on your web? or you want to set up ones working by their own? I mean, you want an iframe or... a javascript file doing all the work on your page withoy any use of iframes?

Comment: I want those same ones on my website.

To clarify, 'my website' is just the game in which these clocks are used. We have a federation board where we can post notices and announcements. HTML works, and ive done popups on page load using javascript, so if it is possible to embed just those clocks, thatd be great.

I have no idea what an iframe is